# Installing fortune on Solaris

Tags: unix, solaris

I'd like to build and install **[fortune](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIX_fortune)** into my home directory on Solaris 10.  Can someone recommend a version that's easy to build on Solaris and comes with a good set of fortune files.  In reading about fortune, it seems I need to first find and choose my source, and then I have to get some fortune files.  I like the version which is bundled with Cygwin.  I'm hoping I can find a single tarball which I can simple make/make install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [fortune-mod-9708.tar.gz](http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/Linux/games/amusements/fortune/fortune-mod-9708.tar.gz).  It doesn't include a configure script, but the Makefile was easy to edit.